# How can I create trigger that represent on front of data on table?

Tags: mysql, database

```
CREATE TABLE db_uts.kode_kabupaten (
  kode_kabupaten varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  nama_kabupaten varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  umr int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (kode_kabupaten)
)

CREATE TABLE db_uts.alternatif (
  id_alternatif varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  jenis_bantuan_id varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  nik varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  nama varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  penghasilan int(7) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_alternatif)
)
```

How can I create a trigger that show on front of data with -hapus- on table alternatif when data from kode_kabupaten deleted?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak6kG.png)

Comment: You should have a nik in table kode_kabupaten which corresponds to nik in table alternatif. Then Trigger can be written to add -hapas- to nik that was deleted

Comment: @AshokAnumula in my table aren't joining table, can I make a trigger based on select only?